# Hibernate Add Model with OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have got an PersonModel which has an address.
Looks like that:

```
public class PersonModel {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private AddressModel address;
}

public class AddressModel {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PersonModel> persons;
}
```

Now, when I get this JSON from my Client:

```
{
    "person": {
        "address": {
            "street": "Examplestreet",
            "city": "Examplevillage"
        }
    }
}
```

And try to save it like that:

```
personModelRepository.save(myJSON.person);
```

Hibernate will always throw a **TransientPropertyValueException**.

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Do I really have to save every single DB-Entry related to person first or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `CascadeType.ALL` at the `@ManyToOne` annotation.

This achieves that your Person gets saved automatically if you save your Address